# VB Update Command w/ Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, syntax-error, sql-update

```
 Function UpdateTableRow()
        sqlLink.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\will\Documents\Computing\ComputingProjectDatabase.accdb';"

    Try
        Dim sqlOrder As New OleDbCommand
        If sqlLink.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            sqlLink.Open()
        End If

        ' Creating the command and its parameter here before entering the loop to avoid a continue'
        ' create and destroy pattern for the OleDbCommand'

        sqlOrder.CommandText = "UPDATE StockSystem SET [Stock Price] =?, [Stock Size] =?, [Stock Quantity] =?, [Stock Category] =?, WHERE [Stock ID] =?"
        sqlOrder.Connection = sqlLink

        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCategory", 0)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockQuantity", 0)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockSize", 0)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockPrice", 0)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row", 0)

        Dim rows = DataGridView1.Rows

        For Each row In rows

            sqlOrder.Parameters("@row").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
            sqlOrder.Parameters("@StockPrice").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
            sqlOrder.Parameters("@StockSize").Value = row.Cells(2).Value
            sqlOrder.Parameters("@StockQuantity").Value = row.Cells(3).Value
            sqlOrder.Parameters("@StockCategory").Value = row.Cells(4).Value

            sqlOrder.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next

        MsgBox("Data Updated.")

        'Problem with the update parameters, works for DELETE FUNCTION, needs to be changed to fit an UPDATE FUNCTION

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        sqlLink.Close()

    End Try
    Return DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Function
```

Hey, so as you can see I have a nice bit of code here. Only it doesn't 100% work. I keep getting told `Syntax Error in UPDATE statement`. Now I'm pretty sure the update statement is correct, as without the parameters if doesn't have an issue with the code (admittedly without the parameters it doesn't work at all). I've been stuck on this for about a week so any help would be great >.<

The second error I get is, because I'm using Access, there is a "blank" row at the bottom of the table. I was thinking something like (row - 1) would work, only it VB 2010 doesn't like that at all.

As I said, any help would be awesome.

Comment: You must add the parameters in the same order as they occur in your update statement, so stock price comes first. BTW Get rid of the spaces in your field / column names before they drive you nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added a `,` before `WHERE` . This is the cause of syntax error in UPDATE statement

Try this

```
sqlOrder.CommandText = "UPDATE StockSystem SET [Stock Price] =?, [Stock Size] =?, [Stock Quantity] =?, [Stock Category] =? WHERE [Stock ID] =?"
```

On the other hand I'm not sure what you mean. This blank row?

[image]

It's just there to allow user to insert a new row. It is not an empty row, so **you don't need to reference the rows with** `rowindex - 1`

**UPDATE:** Trying to correct your code. I would do somethink like this:

```
Try

    If sqlLink.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sqlLink.Open()
    End If

    Dim rows = DataGridView1.Rows

    For Each row In rows

        Dim sqlOrder As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE StockSystem SET [Stock Price] =?, [Stock Size] =?, [Stock Quantity] =?, [Stock Category] =? WHERE [Stock ID] =?", sqlLink)            

        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockPrice", row.Cells(1).Value)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockSize", row.Cells(2).Value)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockQuantity", row.Cells(3).Value)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCategory", row.Cells(4).Value)
        sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@row", row.Cells(0).Value)

        sqlOrder.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next

    MsgBox("Data Updated.")

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    sqlLink.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Without "," I end up with a different error of "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"                                                                                      As for the blank row, that is what I mean, but with the current code, it tries to 'update' every row, but comes into error with the last blank row.

Comment: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` means that the data you are trying to put into the database can't be accepted because the database is expecting a different type of data. In your code you're adding all the parameters as integer `0`. If any field at your database is defined as Text you'll need to add parameters as string. E.g: If `Stock Category` is defined as Short text in Access then use `sqlOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCategory", "0")`

Comment: I have done as you just said and the Error has once more changed to 'Parameter_1? Has no value'. Though the original "save function" still isn't working. Sorry for any inconvenience >.<.

Comment: Add the parameters in the same order as they occur in your update statement

Comment: I have done that and now says 'One or more missing Parameters required'

Comment: Yep. Because you are adding parameters in a loop without declaring a new OleDbCommand on each iteration. See my update

Comment: Sorry >.< made the changes as shown in your update and the result is `Syntax Error in UPDATE statement` again. Also getting a Warning that not all code paths return a value in the function

Comment: Remove de comma before `WHERE` again. The warning is due to my code is just a portion and is not returning any value as yours which is returning `DataGridView1.SelectedRows`

Comment: Awesome! The code is working now thank you so much! There is still the error of `Parameter?_1 has no default value` which is what I thought was the issue with the "blank row". >.<

Comment: Ummmm strange. Are you sure there is a value on  every `row.Cells(1).Value` at the `DataGridView`?

Comment: There's definitely a value on every row, which is why I was assuming it was counting the last 'blank row' as a row, and thus returning a row without a value or parameter. I can't really think what else it could be.

Comment: But your parameters are being added from the `DataGridView`, not from the database table on which i am assuming there is no blank row. Anyway, to hide the last empty row in a `DataGridView` select `Properties > AllowUserToAddRows = false`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the comma before the **Where**, change this:

`([Stock Category] =?, WHERE [Stock ID] =?)`

To this:

`([Stock Category] =? WHERE [Stock ID] =?)`